# Execute Oracle script with SqlPlus; go to state before script processing if any exceptions

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a lot of scripts that contain all kinds of transactions including complex DML and DDL.

I need to find a way to run them fully or not at all. I'd like to see following behavior: if any error occurs in the middle of script processing => go back to the state before the script processing.

I thought I would just put whole script into one big transaction, put a *savepoint* at the beginning and make a rollback to the savepoint in case of any exception, but AFAIK that's impossible, as Oracle does not support nested transactions.

Do you mind sharing your thoughts about that case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy solution for this, because you have DDL in your script. DDL executes `commit` before processing, so `rollback` will not help.

As an alternative you could use flashback option of Oracle. But this impacts the entire database. You create a `flashback restore point`, run the script, if any errors occured then you flashback database to restore point. This will revert all the changes in all the schemas of your database. This is good when you have separate database for running/testing your scripts. It is rather fast. The database should be in archivlog mode.

Another option is to use export/import utility (expdp/impdp). This is also hardly automated in one script, so you do the recovery manually. You take the export dump, run the script, if any errors happened - you restore the dump of your db schemas running impdp.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is the "whenever sqlerror exit" clause. 
Check it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm) out

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but that'd left me with a script not fully executed, not rolled backed to initial state.

Comment: whenever SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK -- would that help?